# How to create multiple Snap shots in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I have read like, we can create multiple snapshot for a SSRS report.But we have to create a default value as a filter if exist.So my question is,at first we add a default value in parameter and deploy the report and set the snap shot option.Then what is meant by multiple snap shots?At a time we have only one default value right?So multiple snapshot means same data will be there for all snapshot right? Also,How can we create mutiple snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are meant for using the same default parameters and having them run on a schedule. That would be useful for a report where the data changes every day and you want to keep a snapshot from every day. Not useful if your data never changes and you want to use different parameter values.

The other option is to use a "Cache refresh plan". You can set up different schedules and different parameter values for these and set it to cache a temporary copy of the report that expires after a day or whatever you like (in minutes).

I use the second option for a report which takes about 30 seconds to run. This is too long for the user (Senior Manager) so I have it set to run at 7am every day and then just show that same cached report to the manager all day no matter how many times the report is run.